# I want to close a div when a link is clicked

Tags: html, css

I have created a message in a `div` with a "close" button. The `div` closes when the "close" button is clicked. I also want the message to close when the link ("support ticket link") is clicked in the `<a>` tag.

```css
#div-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

#checkbox:checked+#div-1 {
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0%;
}

#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#closeBtn {
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#closeBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked />
<div id="div-1" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <table align="center" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="counterwidget panel" style="margin: 0; background-color: lightyellow; box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12) !important;">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="color: #000; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background: lightyellow;" width="100%">
              <div class="panel-footer" style="font-size: 13px; color: #000; background-color: lightyellow; border-top: 0px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" width="100%">
                <p id="closeBtn" style="padding-top: 1rem; float: right">
                  <label for="checkbox" id="closeBtn">&#9747;</label>
                </p>
                <div style="clear: both;" />
                <span class="row" width="100%" style="padding-top: 1rem; text-align: center;">
                  *Important message* ... please click this link:
                  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">[support ticket link]</a>
                </span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way *(not really good practice)* you can set checkbox as `#checkbox` and on click of anchor tag set checkbox's checked value true like this `onclick="checkbox.checked=true"`.

See the Snippet below:

```css
#div-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

#checkbox:checked+#div-1 {
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0%;
}

#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#closeBtn {
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#closeBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked #checkbox />
<div id="div-1" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <table align="center" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="counterwidget panel" style="margin: 0; background-color: lightyellow; box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12) !important;">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="color: #000; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background: lightyellow;" width="100%">
              <div class="panel-footer" style="font-size: 13px; color: #000; background-color: lightyellow; border-top: 0px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" width="100%">
                <p id="closeBtn" style="padding-top: 1rem; float: right">
                  <label for="checkbox" id="closeBtn">&#9747;</label>
                </p>
                <div style="clear: both;" />
                <span class="row" width="100%" style="padding-top: 1rem; text-align: center;">
                  *Important message* ... please click this link:
                  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" onclick="checkbox.checked=true">[support ticket link]</a>
                </span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `checkbox.checked=true` is not really good practice on how to reference an element.

Comment: 100% agree let me add that line in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

just add a onclick function in JS

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('panel-heading')[0].style.display='none'
}
```

```css
#div-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

#checkbox:checked+#div-1 {
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0%;
}

#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#closeBtn {
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

#closeBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked />
<div id="div-1" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <table align="center" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="counterwidget panel" style="margin: 0; background-color: lightyellow; box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12) !important;">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="color: #000; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background: lightyellow;" width="100%">
              <div class="panel-footer" style="font-size: 13px; color: #000; background-color: lightyellow; border-top: 0px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;" width="100%">
                <p id="closeBtn" style="padding-top: 1rem; float: right">
                  <label for="checkbox" id="closeBtn">&#9747;</label>
                </p>
                <div style="clear: both;" />
                <span class="row" width="100%" style="padding-top: 1rem; text-align: center;">
                  *Important message* ... please click this link:
                  <a  onclick='myFunction()' href="https://google.com" target="_blank">[support ticket link]</a>
                </span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the  tag to

```
<a onclick="parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove()" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">[support ticket link]</a>
```

seems to be giving me the desired effect